# TrustZone vs ROM as root-of-trust in Secure Boot

Tags: security, arm, embedded, cortex-m, trustzone

A lot of literature that I stumbled upon referred TrustZone as a mechanism that facilitates Secure Boot (as can be seen [here](https://developer.arm.com/products/architecture/cpu-architecture/m-profile/docs/100690/latest/security-requirements-addressed-by-trustzone-technology-for-armv8-m), and a lot more).

To my knowledge, Secure Boot operates this way:

"*Root-of-Trust verifies img1 verifies img2 ...*"

So in case the chip is booting from a ROM that verifies the first image which resides in a flash memory, what added value do I get by using TrustZone?

It seems to me that TrustZone cannot provide Secure Boot if there is no ROM Root-of-Trust to the system, because it can only isolate RAM memory and not flash, so during run-time, if the non-trusted OS is compromised, it has no way of protecting its own flash from being rewritten.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

> So in case the chip is booting from a ROM that verifies the first image which resides in a flash memory, what added value do I get by using TrustZone?

Secure boot and TrustZone are separate features/functions.  They often work together.  **Things will always depend on your threat model and system design/requirements.**  Ie, does an attacker have physical access to a device, etc.

If you have an image in flash and someone can re-write flash, it may be the case that a system is 'OK' if the boot fails.  Ie, someone can not re-program the flash and have a user think the software is legitimate.  In this case, you can allow the untrusted OS access to the flash.  If the image is re-written the secure boot will fail and an attacker can not present a trojan image.

> Am i missing something here?

If your system fails if some one can stop the system from booting, then you need to assign the flash controller to secure memory and only allow access to the flash via controlled channels between worlds.  In this design/requirement, secure boot might not really do much as you are trying to construct the system to not run un-authorized software.

This is probably next to impossible if an attacker has physical access.  They can disassemble the device and re-program flash by removing, external programming and reinstalling the chip.  Also, an attacker can swap the device with some mocked-up trojan device that doesn't even have the same CPU but just an external appearance and similar behaviour.

---

If the first case is acceptable (rogue code reprogramming flash, but not bootable), then you have designs/requirements where the in-memory code can not compromise functionality of the running system.  Ie, you may not want this code to grab passwords, etc.  So TrustZone and secure boot work together for a lot of cases.  It is entirely possible to find some model that works with only one.  It is probably more common that you need both and don't understand all threats.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure TrustZone can isolate flash depending on the vendor's implementation of the Secure Configuration Register(SCR)

Note this is with regards to TrustZone-M(TrustZone for Cortex-M architecture) which may not be what you are looking for.